# Xcode keyboard not changing in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

When changing the keyboard of my text field, it does not change the keyboard in the simulator. I have already cleared and reset all information from the simulator, but this issue is still persisting, Please assist me.
The keyboard is meant to go away when I click the enter/return button, but Numpad does not feature this, to my knowledge, and for some reason, I cannot change the keyboard.
Here is a video of the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ATFJwAnw3CX85xWomggG6Vkel_ImDmR6/view?usp=sharing

I tried to use the property editor to change the keyboard, but there was no change.

Comment: you can change keyboard type programmatically too. using this code `textFieldView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad`